# How to call HTTPS urls in Netflix Conductor

Tags: https, netflix, conductor

Need help to call URL's which are HTTPS , currently getting below ERROR :

> Failed to invoke HTTP task due to: java.lang.Exception: I/O error on
> POST request for
> "[https://localhost:8080/uri":](https://localhost:8080/uri%22:) PKIX
> path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

where to configure cert in conductor server

1. I tried to keep cert in `JAVA_HOME/security/cacert` file but this is something workaround
2. Also I knew its spring boot project where we can give path in app properties of conductor
3. Raised issue with forum
   https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/discussions/3601
   https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/discussions/3600

Comment: I believe you should use http instead if https in the url